# How to run a specific batch-file in Atom-IDE on specific key sequence?

Tags: batch-file, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

Any Ideas, how to run a specific batch-File inside Atom-IDE (https://ide.atom.io/) on a specific key sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`process-palette`](https://atom.io/packages/process-palette) package allows you to configure any command line instruction you want and bind it to a command within Atom. A configuration like this will allow you to run the active file with a CWD that matches the project directory, just as an example of what you can do:

[image: Process Palette configuration]

Comment: but how can i start my batch-file in its own window (outside of 'process-palettes`s' panel?)

Comment: The package doesn't support that.

Comment: Any idea how to realize that?

Comment: Not without you telling me your operating system.

Comment: Its windows 10.

Comment: `start cmd.exe /k path/to/batch/file`. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc770297(v=ws.11)

Comment: Glad you got it.